# How to revert back to Desktop website from Mobile Website when using CSS Media Queries?

Tags: css, media

I'm using CSS media queries to create a responsive theme. I want to add a link at the footer of the website labeled "GO TO DESKTOP WEBSITE". This link will specifically be displayed on the mobile devices. How can I do it so that when a visitor click on the desktop website link, the website is loaded with desktop media query, not of mobile. I hope I've made myself pretty clear on my issue. I've searched on Google for the solution but can not find anything related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unload your `responsive.css` file using:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].disabled = true;
```

for example you might have:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" type="text/css" id="css_base" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css" type="text/css" id="css_responsive" />
```

then you can have:

```html
<a href="#" class="hidden-desktop" id="site_view">Show Full site</a>
```

```js
$("#site_view").click(function() { 
   $("#css_responsive").prop("disabled", true); 
});
```

Here's a quick example: http://jsbin.com/elukab/1 (just minimize the browser window)

---

or

you can redirect the user to a new URL where you specify that you want the mobile version **off**, for example:

```js
$("#site_view").click(function() { 
   document.location = document.location.href + '?mobile=off';
});
```

and with your dynamic language, just read the query string and don't load the responsive styles, as I'm a .NET developer, I would do:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" id="css_base" />
@if(Request["mobile"] == null || Request["mobile"] != "off") {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css" id="css_responsive" />
}
```

Comment: Well what language is it in the end, which starts with `@if`?

Comment: As I specified, I'm a .NET Developer, for such that's [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) with [Razor View](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) :) - You apply what language you use, PHP, Java, RubyOnRails, etc ... or you can do it the same with javascript as well.

Comment: I guessed it would have been a RazorView, but the question is tagged just for CSS Media Queries. :)

Comment: and I did answer that ... in the first part of my answer, together with the example link is exactly what you can and should do... the second part is to be more creative ...